# Android programming - page with 3 options

Tags: java, android

I have a page which has 3 options: `one`, `two` and `three`. Now I want that when clicking on `one`, a new page opens. I submit some data there and come back to the previous page and do the same with all three options. Please help me with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Activity.startActivityForResult method to launch a new screen and return data back to the original caller.

A quick google of this method name turned up this example:

http://micropilot.tistory.com/1577

That should be a good place to start

Comment: can u suggest how to make a box that is also a link containing some text

Answer (score 0):

> can u suggest how to make a box that
>   is also a link containing some text

sounds like you're looking for a Dialog, [here is a great page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) that shows how to use all of the different types.